# How much memory can an application use in 32bit Linux machine?

Tags: java, linux, memory, operating-system, ram

I'm new to Linux and have a question about memory limitations.
As I know, in Windows you can only have 2.8 GB used in the 32bit version of OS, but what about Linux - is it 4 GB or less too?

**I'm particularly interested in Java application run in RHEL5.
But if you have answers about other technologies - that would be awesome to listen to.**

Comment: In Windows 32-bit the limit for the heap size is closer to between 1.2 and 1.5 GB depending on how many shared libraries have been loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RHEL5 32-bit provides 3G/1G split for user processes and the kernel respectively.

That means a single process can only access up to 3G of address space. The system itself can have more than 4G of RAM, and all of that will be available to the kernel if you're using a PAE kernel. And the kernel will be able to properly distribute that memory across different user processes.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably at most 3Gbytes (but some weird kernel configure options could raise that, perhaps to 3.3Gbytes)

You can lower the available memory limits with the [setrlimit(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) syscall (perhaps thru the `ulimit` bash builtin)

If you have a big iron with much more than 4Gbytes RAM installing a 64 bits distribution should make sense.

You might perhaps consider also [compiling your Java application ahead of time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahead-of-time_compilation) with e.g. [gcj](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/), but that compiler is out of fashion and supports only an old Java standard; and I am not sure you'll win some memory space (perhaps a few megabytes, because its runtime is much smaller than your JVM).

Comment: yeah! 64 is better - but this memory 32/64 crap created a nasty piece of work for me :'(

Comment: @BohdanVoloshyn If you use pure Java, you can switching between 32 and 64-bit without changing or re-compiling your code.

Comment: @Basile, do you really think that `gcj` would be that much better in terms of memory consumption than the JIT found in most JVMs?

Comment: @Brian: I don't really know, but I guess that `gcj` will be only marginally better. You could try to use it, but don't spend much than one or two hours. (and it might fail to compile your code, because the standard supported is not really the latest Java). You certainly won't win much (and you could lose). I guess the main difference might be the size of the runtime.

Comment: @Peter unfortunately it's not just java

Comment: @BohdanVoloshyn You can try a 32-bit application on a 64-bit OS. For UNIX at least this can give you more memory.  For windows 64-bit, it uses a 32-bit virtual machine which has the same limitations. :|